# Editing on Stack Overflow

Tags: discussion, edits, etiquette

Personally, I have a tendency to write politely when I post questions, given the fact I'm asking for help.

I noticed that many times, when editing a question I wrote, the editor deletes the opening 'Hi' or the closing 'Thanks' etc. Is there a real reason to remove curtsies?

I appreciate your thoughts on the subject.

**Edit**

I got the point from the answers so far. I suppose I'll stop using greetings and thanks, if that's the site's spirit.

Comment: They're only polite if they're expected.

Answer (score 4):

From an outsider perspective I understand that it can seem unnecessarily anal to exterminate greetings and signatures from posts, but if you think about it it makes sense. We want to get to the meat of the question as quickly as possible, and every word that isn't describing your problem isn't helping us help you.

None of us mind a question that has no salutation, but here's what happens if you do put one in:

**Pros:**

- You show you're a nice person

**Cons:**

- Clutters up question summary and pushes out useful information
- Slows down reader who is trying to help you
- Potentially makes the question look less professional ("Hai guise", "Sup'" etc.)

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a real reason to remove curtsies?

It is considered noise. It adds *nothing* to the question and takes screen space that is better used for the details of the question.

As a community, greetings, salutations and thanks have been considered unneeded and are thigns that should be removed.

See [Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts)

Comment: I think that deleting 'Hi' or 'Thanks' because _it takes screen space_ is exaggeration. If this is a community decision I'll abide, of course. Can you refer me to such guidelines?

Comment: @Noich - I did. See the linked question and the answers on it.

Answer (score 1):

Greetings and thanks are extra words that are not necessary to who wants to answer the question.

Greetings in particular are more noisy because you are forcing users to read them before to get the question; thanks are less noisy, as they are written after the question itself, but they are still extra words somebody needs to read, to understand if they are information useful to answer the question.